# Greed on C Program trouble saving game to file

Tags: c, file-io

We're having this project of implementing Greed (greedjs.com) in C.  everytime user makes a move, this function should update. as @ moves, it would leave the particular element of my BOARD[ROW][COLUMN] = 0. how can I write it into file so that instead of 0 it would print a space?

here's my code:

```
void update_game_file() {   
    fboard = fopen("newgame.txt", "w+");
    if(fboard==NULL){
       printf("Error!");
       exit(1);
    }
/*
 *  print board to file
 */
for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
        if(BOARD[i][j] == 64)   {
            char player = BOARD[i][j];
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", player);
        } else if (BOARD[i][j] == 0) {
            char space = BOARD[i][j];
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", space);          
        } else if (BOARD[i][j] !=64) {
            fprintf( fboard, "%d", BOARD[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fprintf( fboard, "\n");
}
fclose(fboard);
}
```

Comment: By printing a space instead of 0? I am sorry, your question is very unclear.

Comment: my code would write space on the file but seems to be located on the wrong spot. why is that so? this is my first programming subject so i really appreciate the help

Comment: im sorry `else if (BOARD[i][j] == 0) {
            char space = BOARD[i][j];
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", space);          
        }`  should be `else if (BOARD[i][j] == 0) {
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", ' ');          
        } `

Comment: You can edit the question by clicking the **[edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30425814/edit)** at the left, just below the tags. It would help if you showed a small sample of the output that you're getting.

Comment: @user3386109 isn't OP saying he has solved the problem himself?

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps, but the comment about the "wrong spot" seemed to indicate that there was more to the problem.  Voting to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: @PaoYap what other values does `BOARD[][]` have besides `64` and `0`, that is treated by `else if (BOARD[i][j] !=64)` (which is a redundant test anyway since you already tested for `64`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is one way to handle the problem:

```
for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
    {

        if (BOARD[i][j] == 0)
        {
            fprintf( fboard, " " );
        }

        else if ( BOARD[i][j] == '@' )
        {
            fprintf( fboard, "@" );
        }

        else
        {
            fprintf( fboard, "%d", BOARD[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fprintf( fboard, "\n");
}
```

however, this will cause some problems when reading the file back.

suggest:

```
for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
    {

        if (BOARD[i][j] == 0)
        {
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", ' ' );
        }

        else if ( BOARD[i][j] == '@' )
        {
            fprintf( fboard, "%c", '@' );
        }

        else
        {

            fprintf( fboard, "%c", BOARD[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fprintf( fboard, "\n");
}
```

Comment: im sorry this it what i was trying to say earlier. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mo01wzeu9gqjfnp/AACCb93JWdW8MjeaFFJLaPKFa?dl=0) anyway, this worked thanks.